# Yii CActiveForm validation error

Tags: forms, validation, error-handling, yii

i'm using

```
echo $form->error($model,'username');
```

to display validation errors for attribute. But by default it uses div tag with custom class to wrap message itself. I want to use another tag and class. How can i change it?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you have to override the `error()` method of the `CActiveForm` class. You can also use the `errorMessageCssClass` class property to change the CSS for the error message.

Comment: well, it's pretty sad, i wish to have htmlOption for tag modification

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understood your comment. What do you mean?

Comment: error method have htmlOptions array, to setup output. it seems there is no option to switch tag from div to another one

Comment: Yes, but you can always override the method and use any tag you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the static `errorContainerTag` of `CHtml` before you render the errors in your view file:

```
<?php
CHtml::$errorContainerTag = 'span';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways of accomplishing your result.
You can either use the $errorMessageCssClass property in the definition of the form widget
like this:

```
$form = $this->beginWidget ( 'CActiveForm', array (
'id' => 'test-form',
'enableClientValidation' => true,
'errorMessageCssClass'=>'the error class you want',...........
```

which will apply to all the elements in your form...
OR 
you can be more specific to an item using:

```
<?php echo $form->error($model,'password', array('class'=>'your desired class'); ?>
```

hope it helps